# Only last row of sqlite database is being displayed

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my sqlite database code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ SERVER_ID + " TEXT,"+ ACCESS_TOKEN + " TEXT," + FIRST_NAME
                + " TEXT," + LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + USERNAME + " TEXT," + ADDRESS + " TEXT," + LATITUDE + " TEXT,"
                + LONGITUDE + " TEXT," + BLOOD_GROUP + "  TEXT," + GENDER + " TEXT,"
                + PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT," + MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT," + DOB_YEAR + " TEXT,"
                + DOB_MONTH + " TEXT," + DOB_DAY + " TEXT," + COUNTRY + " TEXT," + IMAGE_URL
                + "  TEXT," + TYPE + " TEXT" +");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
```

and this is my code to get all the values from the table

```
 public HashMap<String, String> getBPositiveData(){
        HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from user where type =? and blood_group =?", new String[]{"friends", "B_plus"});
        //Move to first
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

           do {
                   getData.put("server_id", cursor.getString(1));
                   getData.put("first_name", cursor.getString(3));
                   getData.put("last_name", cursor.getString(4));
                   getData.put("blood_group", cursor.getString(10));
                   getData.put("mobile_number", cursor.getString(13));
                   getData.put("imageURL", cursor.getString(18));
                   cursor.moveToNext();
               int abc = cursor.getCount();
               Log.e("cursorCount", String.valueOf(abc));
           }while (!cursor.isAfterLast());
           cursor.close();
        }
        return getData;
    }
```

In my database all the rows are properly inserted and the query provides me with the required data as well (I checked the database from genymotion emulator so I am sure that the data are present there). My problem is that i only get the value form the last row of that table. Could anyone please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong here?? the code I use to retrieve the values in my activity is this:

```
HashMap<String, String> profile = db.getBPositiveData();
                final String fname = profile.get("first_name");
                final String lname = profile.get("last_name");
                final String bgroup = profile.get("blood_group");
                final String mnumber = profile.get("mobile_number");
                final String iurl = profile.get("imageURL");
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using proper collection? `HashMap` will store only one key-value pair, so it overrides every loop you make. You should use `ArrayList<YourCustomObject>` instead...

Comment: @DamianKozlak I'm not sure if i am. I used this tutorial to create my database. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/. Is there any way i can retrieve all my data from the above code that i'm using?? if Yes could you please provide me with some hints..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class User

public class User {

```
String first_name;
String last_name;
String blood_group;
// ...the rest of the propertied
}
```

Change HashMap declaration for getData

HashMap userList = new HashMap<>();

Then mack a change in your code

```
User currentUser = null;
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{

    do {
        currentUser = new User();
        currentUser.first_name = cursor.getString(3);
        currentUser.last_name = cursor.getString(4);
        currentUser.blood_group = cursor.getString(10);
        // the rest of your data for user
        String rowKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        userList.put(rowKey, currentUser);
        cursor.moveToNext();

        // the rest of your code

    } while (!cursor.isAfterLast());
    cursor.close();
    return userList;
}
```

Then change the return type of your method accordingly from HashMap into HashMap.

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: v_haruty. Yes this approach worked well for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for feadback. You gave me some freedom

Answer (score 0):

Try your "if (cursor.moveToFirst())" as a "while (cursor.next()" loop and return your getData within the loop.

An example of what I am talking about can be seen in [adding data to hashmap from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437028/adding-data-to-hashmap-from-databas).

Answer (score 0):

For every iteration you overide your dara in Hashmap. For example, you can have only one key "server_id". For the first record your code puts

getData.put("server_id", cursor.getString(1));
For the second record when you call

getData.put("server_id", cursor.getString(1));
it overides.

Comment: HI! What should i do to solve this then? Could you provide me with some assistance? I seem to be stuck here. I created the database using the following tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/. If you could provide me with some assistance that would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for one single user ? or a list of users ? . If yu are looking for a list, then one solution could be defining a User class and defining a HashMap of User.

Comment: The solution with a list will post in my answer bellow

Comment: i am looking for a lists of users. The table consists of multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create your object class, ex. `User`

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String bloodGroup;

    private String mobileNumber;

    private String imageUrl;

    public User() {

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBloodGroup() {
        return bloodGroup;
    }

    public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Then to get users B-positive users:

```
public List<User> getBPositiveUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from user where type =? and blood_group =?", new String[]{"friends", "B_plus"});

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();

                user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(3));
                user.setLastName(cursor.getString(4));
                user.setBloodGroup(cursor.getString(10));
                user.setMobileNumber(cursor.getString(13));
                user.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(18));

                users.add(user);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Error while trying to get users from database");
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

1. Try-catch-finally block is always nice when you work with cursor.
2. `user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(3));` is ugly usage. 
   If you have column names as constants (and I assume you are using it, since in creation you use ex. `FIRST_NAME`), it would be better if you change this line and other similar to `user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME)));`
3. Check [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for creating getters and setters for variables. It makes code easier to read :)